# Can the topic-outline follow me in documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation

I like the topic outline in documentation.  I just hate that it sticks to the top of the page and feel that as I scroll all of the topics (As this can be pages and pages long) that it should scroll along with me.

For instance in python I'd like to flip through creating a module and user input, and doing so causes me to continue to scroll back to the top of the page to see the topic outline.

[image]

This should work similiar to the functionality for "Similar Questions" found on the right side when asking a question.  As you scroll the "ask a question page this guy sticks!

Comment: My only concern with this would be that the topic outline is pretty *big*, and that limits the amount of screen space available for me to accomplish my primary task—reading the documentation. Otherwise, I think this a solid proposal.